# 'WHERE' multiple checks

Tags: python, sqlite, tkinter

I want to get name, last and age out of the database if what they entered is correct.

This is my attempt but it doesn't work. If name, last and age is in database it throws it out to the user `simple login`

```
cursor.execute("SELECT *, oid FROM data WHERE name=:name, last= :last, age=:age", 
{
  'name' : name.get()
  'last': last.get()
  'age': age.get()
})
```

This works if I only use one Value etc `WHERE name = :name`.
Any ideas on how I can do this?

Comment: Use AND. `name=:name AND age=:age AND last=:last`

Comment: Why is question this tagged `tkinter`?

Comment: I used tkinter with sqlite3 as you can see in name. Get() and thosw

Comment: @Rhino Yes but is this in any way relevant to the problem you are having? I don't think so, it seems that the issue is only related to the syntax of the database query. Anyway, if there was a problem with the tkinter part, we couldn't see it given of the lack of context.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use "and" instead of ",".

```
cursor.execute("SELECT *, oid FROM data WHERE name=:name and last= :last and age=:age", 
{
  'name' : name.get()
  'last': last.get()
  'age': age.get()
})
```